# CSS dropdown menu not scrolling all the way to the bottom

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu that will not let you scroll all the way to the bottom due to a top margin keeping the popup from appearing on the header. I have tried adding padding but it's not working. Here is the code. Any help is appreciated.

```css
.shifter-enabled .shifter-navigation {
  width: 270px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.001s linear 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.001s linear 0.2s, transform 0.2s ease;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D I cannot scroll all the way to the bottom of the menu leaving the last link in the menu unseen. When I set top to zero, then you can scroll down to see the last menu item. So I have concluded that the top margin being set at 30px is pushing the overflow past a scrollable point.

Comment: I created a quick fix. I added a blank <li> element to create a manual padding. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

remove `height:100%` and add `bottom:0px;`:

```css
.shifter-enabled .shifter-navigation {
  width: 270px;
  position: fixed;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.001s linear 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.001s linear 0.2s, transform 0.2s ease;
}
```

By setting the height to 100% - it will be as tall as the viewport, but as you move it down 30px, it will be 30px off the bottom of the screen.  By setting the top and bottom and no height, it will always be stretched to meet the size of the viewport

Comment: I tried yours so it was cleaner. Perfect fix! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!  You should always fix problems caused by css with css - makes for more maintainable code in the future

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is adding a blank li element to create manual padding.